# Laravel queue:listen takes up all the server memory all the time

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.1, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Amazon Beanstalk to host my Laravel Application. I created a special configuration so that my **queue:listen** will auto re-start on deployment with **supervisor**.

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock
chmod=0777

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/app/support/logs/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=25MB
logfile_backups=2
loglevel=warn
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false
nocleanup=true
user=webapp

[program:laravel_queue]
command=php artisan queue:listen --queue=email,activity,purging,misca --memory=256 --env=production
directory=/var/app/current
stdout_logfile=/var/app/support/logs/laravel-queue.log
logfile_maxbytes=25MB
logfile_backups=2
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=86400
```

This works great and my problem is after a day or too my server memory always reaches 95%!

I inspected the memory and noticed a bunch of http processes that were started by queue:listen but for some reason never killed (note all jobs succeeded, no failure).

```
webapp   22923  0.0  0.4 673948 19032 ?        S    18:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
webapp   22926  0.0  0.8 674588 35512 ?        S    18:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
webapp   22929  0.0  0.4 673948 19032 ?        S    18:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
webapp   22931  0.0  0.9 674932 37576 ?        S    18:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
webapp   22932  0.0  0.4 673948 19032 ?        S    18:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
webapp   22934  0.0  0.8 674600 35536 ?        S    18:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
webapp   22935  0.0  0.8 674588 35512 ?        S    18:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Why are these http processes which I assume are queue:workers not terminating?

Comment: Can you post your job's code?

Comment: Well I have several dozen jobs but they are really not doing anything special. Some call events that trigger handlers and some handlers dispatch other jobs that get pushed on the queue. All in all the queue never fails all the jobs complete but these zombie processes stick around.

Comment: Hmmm, my guess would be that the apache processes are threads listening for incoming web traffic, though I'd expect to see the owner of the threads be apache and not webapp. If the web server is running as webapp though, then that makes sense. I don't _think_ Laravel's queues use apache to run - they run on the command line, don't they?

Comment: well webapp is the user I specified to supervisor to run the queue:listen. When I disable the queue I don't have these processes all over the place so I'm pretty certain these are precisely queue:listen or queue:work processes. (which by the way when I ran the command and got the output above, no jobs were being processed, all have been done hours ago, but these processes remain)

Comment: I assume that some of your jobs failing and because you have set autorestart on true, jobs trying to run again and again. Take a look at documentation about failed jobs https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs

Comment: I have the same issue! It's driving me nuts, I can't find help for this anywhere! In my case I use lumen, I posted this as an issue on github but still no help with it, I'm certain it is a laravel issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

While i am having the same issue, there is an atttribute for the program config for supervisor that you are missing

Try adding `numprocs` and then how many individual process you would like to run

[Reference Laravel's Example Supervisor Config in the Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#supervisor-configuration)